# Jupyter webserver, can't view directories and files

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have setup a Jupyter Notebook Server on an AWS server, using the Andaconda distribution. I can login to the Jupyter web application on the public IP address but Jupyter doesn't list the directories or files. I can see them when I am using the private IP address (using RDP into the machine).

I suspect it may have to do something with the windows accounts.
Any insight what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer myself. I have a Windows account specifically for the Jupyter user (Guest, Power User). I have tried adding Administrator to this account as well but it didn't resolve the issue.

The solution is even easier, you just have to run the Jupyter Notebook Server as Administrator.

There you have it if you ever run into the same issue that I had.